# How to draw a regression formula in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression, draw

I have a pooled result from multiple datasets with:

intercept = 22.35

slope = -1.23

Or alternatively, Y = 22.35 - 1.23*X1

How can I create a regression line in R based on this information?

Comment: By "create a regression line" do you mean "plot this line"?

Comment: In base R, `curve(22.35 - 1.23 * x, from = -2, to = 10)`. See the dupe for other options

Comment: If you have an existing base plot, you can use `abline` to add a line, `abline(intercept, slope)`. If you are using `ggplot`, you can use `geom_abline`.